# How can I add an Alert on StackScreen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a question about this code, I want to add an Alert if you press the BackButton but only in 2 navigation screen (MARKETPLACE and SHOP)
The Alert is to confirm is you want to back or cancel if not
How can I do that?
My BackButton is the first Stack.Screen
This is the code:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen
  name='Root'
  component={DrawerNavigator}
  options={{
  headerShown: false,
  title: '',
  headerBackTitle: 'BackButton
  }}/>
      <Stack.Screen options={{ title: 'MARKETPLACE' }} name='Marketplace' component={Marketplace} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{ title: 'SHOP' }} name='Shop' component={Shopping} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{ title: 'CHECKOUT' }} name='Checkout' component={Checkout} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{ title: 'CHECK' }} name='Check' component={CheckSuccess} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/customBackNavigation/

Comment: thanks! but I don't understand how can I add the alert if I have the backButton like this code:(

Comment: I think the doc I linked only works on v7 of RNN.  Here's a custom hook a user made to handle cross-platform back events. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9027#issuecomment-784432182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `@react-navigation/native` version `5.7+` you can add `beforeRemove` listener to the navigation object to prevent going back.

EXAMPLE

```
function Marketplace({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }

        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
              // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [navigation, hasUnsavedChanges]
  );

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      placeholder="Type something…"
      onChangeText={setText}
    />
  );
}
```

[Check more Details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/)

Comment: thanks! but what happend if I have the <Stack.screen> as I show in the code above  and I only want that in two screens the BackButton show the alert , the Alert function has 2 options, when you press cancel do nothing, when you press "ok" only goBack

Comment: You need to implement ```navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {...})``` in the screens that you that you want to implement the alert screens and implement your logic based on your need.

Comment: sorry & thank u so much!!, 
I finally understood and now it works!! thanks!! :D

Comment: That is Great!!